# How can I loop over an array of sets/maps with varying data types

Tags: kotlin

I want to make it so that I keep my code dry and create 3 (or more, or less) buttons with somewhat the same structure. So I create a list of objects to loop over and put the data inside the object to use in several places in the AppButton.

I might think a bit too Pythonic, because that's my main language and I only recently started using Kotlin. What I normally do in Python:

```py
app_buttons = [
    dict(
        text="....",
        icon="....",
        uri_string="....",
    ),
    ...
]
```

I've tried something similar in Kotlin with `mapOf`:

```kotlin
val appButtons = arrayOf(
    mapOf(
        "title" to getString(R.string.app_btn_example1),
        "icon" to R.drawable.ic_some_icon_1_64,
        "uriString" to "myapp://example1",
    ),
    ...
)
```

and then loop over them and getting from the map:

```kotlin
for (entry in appButtons) {
    buttons.add(
        AppButton(
            entry.get("text"),
            entry.get("icon"),
        ) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(entry.get("uriString"))).apply {
                val name = getString(R.string.saved_account_key)
                putExtra(name, sharedPref.getString(name, null))
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    )
}
```

But then I get `Type mismatch. Required String. Found {Comparable & java.io.Serializable}?`. I don't know what types to put where...

Ok different approach, using `setOf` and destructuring:

```kotlin
val appButtons = arrayOf(
    setOf(
        getString(R.string.app_btn_example1),
        R.drawable.ic_some_icon_1_64,
        "myapp://example1",
    ),
    ...
)

for ((text, icon, uriString) in appButtons) {
    buttons.add(
        AppButton(
            text,
            icon
        ) {
            ...
        }
    )
}
```

But now I get the following:

> Destructuring declaration initializer of type Set<{Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable}> must have a 'component1()' function

> Destructuring declaration initializer of type Set<{Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable}> must have a 'component2()' function

> Destructuring declaration initializer of type Set<{Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable}> must have a 'component3()' function

How do I make this work? How do I create a basic list of objects and loop over them with the correct types? It feels so simple in Python. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Please, do not use maps this way. Create a data class called `ButtonModel` or something like that.

Comment: @Sweeper yea that's why I'm asking. I feel like I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what and how it should be done.

Comment: Kotlin (on the JVM anyway) is a statically typed language (where the types, `Int`, `String` etc are known at compile time), Python is dynamically typed (the types are checked at runtime). That lets you create `dict`s that contain basically whatever, and it's up to you to ensure the stuff pulled out is handled correctly - you have to know `icon` is an `Int` and treat it as one, or you'll get a runtime crash. You can't (normally) do that in statically typed languages - they enforce the correct use of types, so you can't mix them in a map. A data structure like Sweeper's answer is what you need!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using maps, you should create a data class. For example:

```
data class ButtonModel(
     val title: String,
     val icon: Int,
     val uriString: String,
)
```

You can then create the array like this:

```
val appButtons = arrayOf(
    ButtonModel(
        title = getString(R.string.app_btn_example1),
        icon = R.drawable.ic_some_icon_1_64,
        uriString = "myapp://example1",
    ),
    ...
)
```

Or without the parameter labels if you prefer:

```
val appButtons = arrayOf(
    ButtonModel(
        getString(R.string.app_btn_example1),
        R.drawable.ic_some_icon_1_64,
        "myapp://example1",
    ),
    ...
)
```

Then, rather than getting them with `get` or `[]`, you can just use the dot syntax:

```
buttons.add(
    AppButton(
        entry.text,
        entry.icon,
    ) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(entry.uriString)).apply {
            val name = getString(R.string.saved_account_key)
            putExtra(name, sharedPref.getString(name, null))
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
)
```

Comment: At a pinch, you could use a [`Triple`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/) for this. But a custom class is much clearer, safer, and more readable. (It's also very quick to define in Kotlin; it could even be a one-liner!)